# $p$-norms inequalities

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

I got this math homework and I can't do it.

I have to prove the inequalities for p-norms in $\mathbb R^n$:

1. $\|x\|_1\ge\|x\|_2\ge\|x\|_\infty$
2. $\|x\|_1\le\sqrt{n}\|x\|_2$ (I have already proven this one.)
3. $\|x\|_2\le\sqrt{n}\|x\|_\infty$
4. $\|x\|_1\le\sqrt{n}\|x\|_\infty$

Can you help me with the others, please? Thank you very much!

Comment: Context, please? What space do these vectors inhabit? I'm guessing $\mathbb R^n$ or $\mathbb C^n$, but this needs to be stated.

Comment: These vectors are in Rn
I'm sorry, i just started using this page...

Comment: The last one should be $\|x\|_1\le n\|x\|_\infty$ I guess. Check $x=(1,1,1,1)$.

Comment: It is pretty straightforward, just use the definition of the norms and obvious estimations like $|x_k|\le\|x\|_\infty$ etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will do the first one to get you started, and sketch the others.

Write $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n)$. Then:

- $\|x\|_{\infty} = \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} |x_j|$
- $\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{|x_1|^2 + |x_2|^2 + \cdots + |x_n|^2}$
- $\|x\|_1 = |x_1| + |x_2| + \cdots + |x_n|$

First, note that for any $1 \leq j \leq n$, we have $|x_j|^2 \leq |x_1|^2 + |x_2|^2 + \cdots + |x_n|^2$, and therefore, taking square roots, $|x_j| \leq \|x\|_2$. Since this is true for every $j$, it is true for whichever $j$ maximizes $|x_j|$, and therefore $\|x\|_{\infty} = \max |x_j| \leq \|x\|_2$.

Next, note that $|x_1|^2 + |x_2|^2 + \cdots + |x_n|^2 \leq (|x_1| + |x_2| + \cdots + |x_n|)^2$, since all of the terms on the left hand side appear on the right hand side (along with other nonnegative terms) when you expand the right hand side. Therefore, taking square roots, we get $\|x\|_2 \leq \|x\|_1$.

You already got (2), so I'll skip that one.

For (3), note that each $|x_j|$ is no larger than $\max_{1\leq j \leq n}|x_j| = \|x\|_{\infty}$, so $|x_1|^2 + |x_2|^2 + \cdots + |x_n|^2 \leq n (\|x\|_{\infty})^2$. It should be clear what to do next.

(4) is false as stated. However, the inequality $\|x\|_1 \leq n\|x\|_{\infty}$ is true, because as in (3), each $|x_j|$ is no larger than $\max_{1\leq j \leq n}|x_j| = \|x\|_{\infty}$, therefore $|x_1| + |x_2| + \cdots |x_n|$ is no larger than...?

Comment: You're awesome! I really appreciate all the help. I have another question, which program do yo use to write all the math signs?

Comment: @Mariana_Estrada: It's called MathJax. It is built into the site, so it's easy to use. Here is a tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference